# React Native:sub view was not reloading with state change

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

One component `Itie` in React Native 0.62.2 app has a sub view component `ButtonInHead`. `ButtonInHead` returns a enabled Save button when state `post` becomes `true`. Here is the code:

```
import { Button, Left, Right, Body, Icon, Label, Item, Input, Text, Card, CardItem, Header, Container, Content, Form } from 'native-base';


const Itie = () => {  //<<<===component Itie
    const [post, setPost] = useState(false);  //<<<==state post is false initially

    const ButtonInHeader = ({enabled}) => {  //<<<==sub view component 
        if (enabled) {
            return (<Button hasText onPress={clickSave}>
                        <Text>Save</Text>
                    </Button>)
        } else {
            return (<Button hasText disabled >
                        <Text>Save</Text>
                    </Button>)
        };
    };    

    const clickSave = async () => {
          Alert.alert("Save clicked");
    };
    
    return (
        <SafeAreaView> 
            <ScrollView>
                <Container>
                    <Header transparent>
                        <Right>
                            <ButtonInHeader enable={post} /> //<<<==when state post becomes true. button shall be enabled
                        </Right>
                    </Header>
                    <Content>
                        <Form>
                        ......
                        </Form>
                    </Content>
                </Container>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    
    );
};
```

The problem is the after `post` becomes `true`, the sub view component `ButtonInHead` was not reloaded (on android simulator) and the button stays disabled. Since the state `post` is passed into `ButtonInHead` and my understanding is that whenever `post` changes, then `ButtonInHead` shall be reloaded. Obviously it is not all of it. How to force reloading `ButtonInHead` whenever `post` changes?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by introducing state `post` into the `ButtonInHead` by doing:

```
return (<Button hasText onPress={clickSave} disabled={!post}>
                        <Text>Save</Text>
                    </Button>)
```

Actually, `ButtonInHead` is no longer needed and can be replaced with:

```
<Button hasText onPress={clickSave} disabled={!post}>
                            <Text>Save</Text>
                        </Button>
```